# data is not stored in database when follow button is pressed

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a follow button that when I press on it store into follow table followerid and followingid and turned into unfollow
and when I press on unfollow delete them from follow table 
I used JQuery for this 
but when I press on the button it turned into unfollow but does not store any data in the data base can you help me find the error please

**JQuery**

```
function change( el )
{
var input= $('#followingid').val();
var input2=$('#followerid').val();

    if ( el.value == "Follow" )
    {
        $.get("follow_button.php",{following_id:'input',follower_id:'input2'});
        el.value = "Unfollow";
    }
    else
    {
        $.get("unfollow_button.php",{following_id:'input',follower_id:'input2'});
        el.value = "Follow";
    }

}
```

and this is the **follow button**

```
  <form action="" method="post" name="f1">
```

```
<input type="button" value="<?php 
$sql="SELECT * FROM follow WHERE followerid=$id and followingid=$projectid";
$q=mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
    if($num=mysql_num_rows($q))
    echo 'Unfollow';
    else
    echo 'Follow';

    ?>" onclick="return change(this);" />
  </form>
```

and this is `follow_button.php` page

```
<?php
  $followerid=$_GET['follower_id'];
  $followingid=$_GET['following_id'];

  $sql2="INSERT INTO follow (followerid,followingid) VALUES($followerid,$followingid)"; 
  $q2=mysql_query($sql2) or die(mysql_error());
?>
```

**`unfollow_button.php` page**

```
<?php
  $follower_id=$_GET['followerid'];
  $following_id=$_GET['followingid'];

    $sql2="DELETE FROM follow WHERE followingid=$following_id and followerid=$follower_id";
    $q2=mysql_query($sql2); 
?>
```

I review my code several times but I could't find the error ,,I hope you can find the problem
thanx ...

Comment: **Danger**: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).  You are also **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that a modern API would make it easier to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: Any error in console/network tab??? What are you expecting to pass as data here: `following_id:'input'`?

Comment: Your code is indeeed vulnerable to SQL injections. First thing you could also correct in the code of your `unfollow_button.php` page is change the GET parameter names, since you seem to have forgotten the underscores there.

Comment: Trace the HTTP call (either with the browser's built in debugging tools or with a third party application such as Fiddler), and check the actual call that's being made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some problems in your jQuery code. You need to remove the quotes from `'input'` and `'input2`' in your `$.get` calls, otherwise it will just pass the values 'input' and 'input2' literally, instead of the values of the variables.

```
function change(el) {
var input = $('#followingid').val();
var input2 = $('#followerid').val();

    if (el.value == "Follow") {
        $.get("follow_button.php", {following_id: input, follower_id: input2}); // Removed quotes
        el.value = "Unfollow";
    } else {
        $.get("unfollow_button.php", {following_id: input, follower_id: input2}); // Removed quotes
        el.value = "Follow";
    }

}
```

Secondly, in your `unfollow_button.php`, you misspelled your GET parameter names:

```
<?php
  $follower_id=$_GET['follower_id']; // Added an underscore
  $following_id=$_GET['following_id']; // Added an underscore

    $sql2="DELETE FROM follow WHERE followingid=$following_id and followerid=$follower_id";
    $q2=mysql_query($sql2); 
?>
```

Also check the JavaScript console for errors. You could also try manually going to your `follow_button.php` page with GET parameters that would normally work and see if the page shows an error.

Moreover, you are using an outdated database API. Consider using [`PDO`](http://php.net/PDO) with its [`prepare()`](http://php.net/pdo.prepare) function, which will protect you from SQL injections.

For example, if one were to replace the `follower_id` by `15; DROP TABLE follow`, your final SQL query would look like this: `DELETE FROM follow WHERE followingid=42 AND followerid=15; DROP TABLE follow`, which would delete your `follow` table.

Comment: thank you for your answer ,, but I change my code as you told my but nothing change it does not go to follow_button.php I tried to put alert there but no action happened either

Comment: Have you tried manually going to your PHP script called by your AJAX call as suggested?

Comment: yes I tried but it seems it does not go to follow_button.php code

Comment: What do you mean by `yes I tried but it seems it does not go to follow_button.php code`? Does the page show an error or not?

Comment: I mean when I press on follow it should go to follow_button page where it store the data in follow table ,, I put an alert to show (hello) before insert any data but the alert didn't show up

Comment: Technically, it doesn't go to the page, it does an AJAX call, so the page is loaded in the background. An alert inside your PHP page cannot show. Did you check the JavaScript console for errors?

Comment: yes exactly ,,, no I didn't because I don't know how to do it sorry x_x

Comment: See [here](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers)

Comment: thank you very much MR. PLPeeters and sorry for bothering you ^_^

Comment: You're not bothering me, this is what StackOverflow is for. If my answer solved your question, please [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 1):

First check your `mysql connection` and if data is inserted or not you can return an error/success status which would indicate you to change FOLLOW or UNFOLLOW like,

```
if ( el.value == "Follow" ) {
    $.get("follow_button.php",{following_id:'input',follower_id:'input2'}, function(data){
        // change text if you get success in response
        if(data=='success') {
           el.value = "Unfollow";
        }
    });        
} else {
    $.get("unfollow_button.php",{following_id:'input',follower_id:'input2'}, function(data){
        // change text if you get success in response
        if(data=='success') {
           el.value = "Follow";
        }
    });
}
```

In **PHP** try this,

```
$sql2="INSERT INTO follow (followerid,followingid) VALUES($followerid,$followingid)"; 
if(mysql_query($sql2)) echo 'success';
else echo 'error';
return;
```

Do the same for `delete/Unfollow`.

You can combine the `insert and delete code` in a single page by using a `type=follow/unfollow`

Comment: I edited my code as you told my but when I press the follow button it does not change to unfollow + didn't store any data

Comment: In the call back use `alert(data);` and echo `mysql_error()`, you will get your answer

Comment: I put an alert in the beginning of the page to show (hi) but it didn't show up ,,that's it didn't go to follow_button.php

Answer (score 0):

```
function change( el )
{
var input= $('#followingid').val();
var input2=$('#followerid').val();
if ( el.value == "Follow" )
{
    $.get("follow_button.php",{following_id:'input',follower_id:'input2'});
    el.value = "Unfollow";
    return false;
}
else
{
    $.get("unfollow_button.php",{following_id:'input',follower_id:'input2'});
    el.value = "Follow";
    return false;
}
return false;
}
```

Try this..May be this can help you.

Comment: thanx for the answer but nothing change sorry

Comment: check response in console window of firebug.